# How to write a test case to check whether a function is working correctly using testthat in r?

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, testthat

I have lots of functions to check whether each of them is working perfectly. I'm very new to using 'testthat' package. First my code has to read the data from a location

```
  baseData = fread(file = "./Data/ABC.csv", data.table = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, showProgress = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Next I want to filter the data based on a particular column say ab_010 = 10. This is the code for that,

```
  baseData = baseData %>% filter(., ab_010 == 10)
```

Now I want to check whether the filtering has been done correctly using testthat.  Also I have gone through many R bolgs such as this https://b-rodrigues.github.io/fput/unit-testing.html. But I didn't get a clear idea as how to apply this case to my scenario.
This is the piece of code I wrote using testthat,

```
test_that("To check Base data is being read correctly",{
  expected <- fread(file = "./Data/ABC.csv", data.table = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, showProgress = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
  actual <- fread("./Data/ABC.csv")
  expect_equal(expected,actual)
})
```

The test is failing! Where do I need to change things?

Comment: Are you making a package? if so, recommend using `usethis` package to set up testing infrastructure.  If not a package, you might want to use `assertr`

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways to test the behaviour of a function like this:

1. Run the function, and inspect the output carefully. If you are absolutely sure that the output is correct, you can then save this output (using dput, for example) and then compare this correct version to the version returned by the function.
2. Implement the same logic independently of the function, and compare the output of the function to the output of this independent code.

The first is likely more robust, since for case 2., the same error could be implemented in both the test and the function. However it is often more time-consuming, since it also depends on your being certain that the saved output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to do so. First let me share the resources where I got good knowledge about how to use 'testthat'.
https://r-pkgs.org/tests.html. This site has a very good explanation by the author itself about testthat.

What is testthat and how can it be used for unit testing?
I read a lot about testthat and this is the brief explanation about it. 
First of all, 'testthat' is a package in R for doing unit testing. It mainly consists of three concepts,

1. Expectations
2. Tests
3. Files

***Expectations***

So the basic unit of testing would be expectation. These are nothing but the test case or what we would we like to test. The code for expectation should start with expect_. There are more than 15 expectations in testthat package. Most commonly used is "expect_that". The syntax of this would be **expect_that(actual result, expected result)**. Some other expectations commonly used would be *expect_true(),expect_false(),expect_output()* etc...

***Test***

Test are nothing but the expectations we want to test. It is done using the keyword test_that()
The syntax for test_that is **test_that(description about the test,conditions to test(expectations))**.

***Files***

Files are the test file. The file to test should start with test_filename.

**How to know if the test is executed or not?**

Once the code is executed if it is ran and goes to the next line, then the test has succeed.
If the test fails, it returns a error message.

**How I solved my problem?**

My problem was to check whether the filtering has been occurred correctly.
This is the code for that,

```
test_that("Filtering of ab010 == 10 as expected",{
  require("dplyr")
  expect_true(unique(baseData[,"ab010"]) == 10)
})
```

**If the test fails it throws an error message like this**

```
Error: Test failed: 'Filtering of ab010 == 10 as expected'
* unique(baseData[, "ab010"]) == 10 isn't true.
```

This solved my problem.